# Wrong encoding shown in notepad ++ when opening an xml written using XMLStreamWriter in java

Tags: java, encoding

Facing a strange problem. I have an application in java which writes data to an xml file. This application is part of a bigger project and has multiple dependencies.
When I open the xml file in notepad ++, wrong encoding is highlighted .
This is a minimal reproducible example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
     OutputStream ostream;
     XMLStreamWriter writer;
     Path path = Paths.get("C:/encodingissue/711.xml");
    ostream = Files.newOutputStream(path);
    XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    writer = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(ostream,  "ISO-8859-1");
    writer.writeStartDocument("ISO-8859-1", "1.0");
      writer.writeStartElement("county");
      writer.writeCharacters("bærum");
      writer.writeEndElement(); 
      writer.close();
      ostream.close();
}
```

Strange thing is, there was a new branch cut out few days back. When I execute the above code in the old branch, no issues. Notepad ++ shows ISO-8859. I compared the code with previous branch. no change there. Any idea what could be the issue? spend 2 days, no clue ..
[image]

wrong encoding: [image]

Comment: What is `ENCODING`? And how can Notepad say that the encoding is wrong when the file contains only plain ASCII characters?

Comment: @tgdavies edited , there was a typo. when  i say notepad , i mean, notepad ++ highlights  the encoding . it should match the one we provide in the java code.

Comment: What encoding does Notepad++ think your file is in?

Comment: An XML file with just that one element without any characters outside the ASCII range will look almost exactly the same in most common one-byte encodings as well as UTF-8, because they all represent characters <= U+007F as a single byte. So the only difference will be the character set name in the header. What exactly Notepad++ displays depends on what information Notepad++ considers when deciding on the encoding. But whatever it displays is by no means authorative.

Comment: i have added the two pngs- correct and the wrong one. the acual program contains letters outside ASCII range. this is just a minimalistic representation

Comment: @Parameswar: then you over-simplified. Please produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that actually *produces* the problematic difference.

Comment: This example doesn't reproduce the problem then. With that file the two encodings are equally correct.

Comment: I see a change of double quote to **single apostrophe** for the XML attributes. Probably the parsing of the encoding cannot deal with a single apostrophe. At whatever point in the communication. Maybe Notepad++ expects only double quotes. Try a web browser.

Comment: @JoachimSauer , done. added a line with non ascii character. only srange thing is notepd++ highlights a wrong encoding.  but the chacaters are not blurred , they appear ok.

Comment: @JoopEggen i noted that as well. the problem is, browser (ie) parses it correctly.  thing is, we pass this xml into a third party xml parser which is not able to recognize the new xml. i assume it has the same parser notepad ++ has.

Comment: @JoachimSauer if you see the second pic, notepad ++ highlights ANSI, but thats not the case. as joop eggen pointed out, i see a quote change, but the code has not changed from the previous working version which is i am confused what coould have caused the change

Comment: "ANSI" is a misleading name for an encoding at best and useless at worst. Basically: Notepad++ tries to guess the encoding and may or may not get it right. If this is your *only* problem with the resulting output, then I'd strongly encourage you to ignore it, because it's probably just Notepad++s encoding detection algorithm producing slightly wonky results due to a different set of quotes being used. But nothing seems wrong about either file. If you actually have a *real* issue (not related to what Notepad++ shows down there), then please describe that.

Comment: well, we pass on this file to a third party app which does not recognize the encoding. and the team member told us that encoding is wrong and they used notepad ++ to justify their point. i am trying to find out what is wrong here.

Comment: Why not [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) in **2020**?

Comment: @Parameswar: Again, Notepad++ is not an authorative source on the encoding of anything. It's **guessing** (granted, with some non-terrible algorithms, but still). Any correct XML parser (used correctly) will parse the XML produced by your sample code correctly. That should be the **only** relevant condition for producing correct XML. Anything else is made-up cargo-cult programming and not understanding the underlying technology.

Comment: What exactly does the third party app say?

Comment: we dont have access to that, the team says encoding is wrong. they justfy it by opening it in notepad ++. @tgdavies

Comment: @Parameswar you need to talk to that team's manager and tell them that you are not being given enough information to solve the problem. I would expect the other team to be able to say "When the character X appears in the document is is represented by the byte 0xYY which is incorrect for ISO-8859-1".